# Understanding widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I'm a newbie programmer and am currently learning python with kivy as a GUI platform.

I am reading the kivy manual and was working on widgets. I wanted to try some stuff on the tutorial painter widget, but after hours of trying, failed to do so.

What I want should be quite simple. I have the widget where it creates a random line after touching the screen. I thought it would be fun to automatically add lines repeatedly after touching the screen at a certain area. So I made a function that keeps "injecting" the widget with data to create more lines.

But I simply can not "communicate" with the widget. I have no idea what the widget "instance" name is. So I created the instance by naming it painter, well let's just share the code:

```
import kivy
import time
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch,):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(random(), random(), random())
            touch.ud['Line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
            touch.ud['Line'].points += [random()*1000, random()*1000 ]
        begin()

    def touchme():
        touch.ud['Line'].points += [random()*1000, random()*1000 ]
        print 'touchme'

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        return painter

def begin():
    def my_callback(dt):
        print 'begin'
        painter.touchme()
    Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 1.)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Hopefully soneone can provide me with an answer of how to do that and maybe explain to me a bit how the widgets work. I'm treating it as a standard class in python, but I think it works a little different than that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve, but I guess you could just move the code from your `begin` method into the `on_touch_down` method, to make the latter look like this:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(random(), random(), random())
        touch.ud['Line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        touch.ud['Line'].points += [random()*1000, random()*1000 ]
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.touchme, 1.)
```

The problem is that `touchme` needs the `touch` object, so you'd have to pass it as a parameter. Sth like this might work, but I didn't check:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(random(), random(), random())
        touch.ud['Line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        touch.ud['Line'].points += [random()*1000, random()*1000 ]
    Clock.schedule_interval(lambda: self.touchme(touch), 1.)

def touchme(self, touch):
    touch.ud['Line'].points += [random()*1000, random()*1000 ]
    print 'touchme'
```

Generally I'd recommend you try to get a better feeling for variable scopes. In your code you try to access the variables `painter` and `touch` where they just aren't visible.

I'm only getting started with kivy myself, so maybe I can give a more complete answer in a few weeks. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I indeed already found that i'm using variables that are only viable within seperate functions. I have altered the code and put the pointer within the build(self) definition and than it worked by using painter...